# Como usar algo semelhante ao BorderLayout em Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

Estou fazendo um projeto usando o Qt, e senti falta do `BorderLayout`, alguém saberia me dizer se ele existe no Qt? se não, tem algum parecido com ele?

Comment: Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 2):

Não existe uma classe pronta na biblioteca mas há um [exemplo na documentação](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-layouts-borderlayout-example.html) mostrando como fazer algo semelhante.